# Cucumber/Capybara tests returning Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError when I visit url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am unable to visit the following url "http://localhost:7000/login/next=" 
In my page object i have set the following:

```
class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page
    set_url "/login/next="
```

and I have set the following in my env.rb file

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:7000"
Capybara.server_host = "localhost"
Capybara.server_port = "7000"
```

and required the following:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
```

When I run test it get the following

```
Cannot assemble URI string with ambiguous path: ':7000/login/next='(Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Capybara doesn't like the port/host in the url. Any ideas who to get rounds this please?

Comment: And what code is in `set_url` method?

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/site_prism/SitePrism/Page#set_url-class_method

Comment: I would suggest setting the port and host in `config/test.rb`. Setting it within Capybara overrides the default test environment. Can you post your Cucumber test?

Comment: yes i had set it in feature/support/env.rb    Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:7000"
Capybara.server_host = "localhost"
Capybara.server_port = "7000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set Capybara.app_host when you are running locally.  From [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

> Normally Capybara expects to be testing an in-process Rack
>   application, but you can also use it to talk to a web server running
>   anywhere on the internet, by setting app_host:
>
> `Capybara.current_driver = :selenium 
>   Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com' 
>   ... 
>   visit('/')`

You should be fine just setting the `Capybara.server_port = 10000`.  Also I think the server_port expects a number not a string.